# How to ignore a field in Database with java sql query Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have 5 rows in MS Access database one of them is Serial Number whose property is auto number I am trying to pass this query to the database to insert.

```
int s= sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO stockDB VALUES('"+name+"','"+size+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')");
```

In the database the Serial Number is the first column then the name,size,quantity and price.

When I am trying to do the insert i get this error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

I know i should put something in the first but what should i put it there?
I tried to put the Serial Number at the last but the error was the same.
What should i put in the query so that the sql accepts it but still genrates auto number in the database?

Comment: INSERT INTO stockDB(name, size, quantity, price) VALUES( .. you should specify the column names and you are good to go

Comment: Why dont you specify the column name.Something like INSERT into [stockDB]([USERNAME],[SIZE],[QUANTITY],[PRICE]) values (?,?,?,?)";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your sql query is wring
do like this

```
int s= sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO stockDB(name,size,quantity,price) VALUES('"+name+"','"+size+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')");
```

you need not to insert serial number manually because its auto increment but you have to specify the rest of the column names and values to be inserted and serial number value will be inerted automatically as its auto increment

Answer (score 1):

try using different format of the query -

```
int s = sta.executeUpdate("insert into stockDB ('name', 'size', 'quantity', 'price') values('" + name + "','" + size + "','" + quantity + "','" + price + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Serial number field as AUTO_INCREMENT to automatically generate value for the field on inserting eecord in table.

Then specify field names in INSERT query and supply values.